# How to remove notification list from tray clock dropdown in 18.04

Tags: unity, notification, calendar

After installing 18.04 the position of the time display moved from the upper right corner to the center of the tray. In addition a notification list appears along with the calendar display. The notification list takes up a lot of desktop real estate blocking windows underneath it. So when I have the calendar open while, say writing a memo in LibreOffice I can no longer see both the calendar and LibreOffice. When I click anywhere off the calendar display it disappears requiring it to be reopened.

I want the calendar display to not show notifications (a separate functionality), to be positioned to the side and to be sticky. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There is a gnome shell extension called extend panel menu.. But it will alter lot of things not just calender n notifications.. But try this extension once.. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/

Comment: Please edit the question to remove unity tag.. Based on your question its clear that u have not installed unity on Ubuntu 18.04 install